# CKAN: How to get dataset name?

Tags: customization, ckan

I want to customize the template for every single dataset, using the dataset name for sharing button.

Is there a variable to get the dataset name?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sometimes varies depending on what page's template you're editing, but a lot of the time one of `c.pkg.name`, `c.pkg_dict.name`, `pkg.name` or `pkg_dict.name` should work.

To find out how to see for sure exactly what variables are available to each template, read http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming/variables-and-functions.html